# VBA search table exclude blank cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a search table in excel and I want to use a VBA code to search for specific words in the rest of the workbook. Here is an example of my table.

Fruits
Store
Area

I have set these values as a string, but I am having a trouble with having one item blank and then running the macro.  So if i want to find only fruit and area, it wont run because store is left blank.  Is there a way I can search the workbook without having each line filled in?

Here is the code I am using to copy the data over.

```
finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row



For i = 1 To finalrow
If Cells(i, 1) = Fruits And Cells(i, 2) = Store And Cells(i, 3) = Area  Then
Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 3)).Copy
ssheet.Select (Workbook sheet to paste)
Range("A100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: The Or gives me a result for any of the two words and I want it to return the value that has only the two criteria

Comment: How do you determine which criteria you need ultimately. You always want it to find only times when `Fruit` and `Area` are there regardless of whether `Store` is blank or filled in?

Comment: Hello, I would like it to find the values of Fruit and Area match  even if store is left blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use IIF():

```
If IIF(Fruits<>"",Cells(i, 1) = Fruits,True) And _
   IIF(Store<>"",Cells(i, 2) = Store,True) And _ 
   IIF(Area<>"",Cells(i, 3) = Area,True)  Then
```

Also avoid the use of Select.  Also when just wanting the values just assign the value and skip the clipboard:

```
With ActiveSheet
    finalrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To finalrow
        If IIf(Fruits <> "", .Cells(i, 1) = Fruits, True) And _
           IIf(Store <> "", .Cells(i, 2) = Store, True) And _
           IIf(Area <> "", .Cells(i, 3) = Area, True) Then

           ssheet.Range("A100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 3).Value = .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 3)).Value
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: This did not work, is there something else I am missing?

Comment: What do you mean by, did not work.  That could be a lot of things.

Comment: Hello, the last part is not working.  It is saying .Range and .Cell are invalid or unqualified references

Comment: The code above works for me, not sure why you are getting the error.  You may want to remove the `.` in front of those items.  I used a With Block that you are not using. @Tara

Comment: hello, It still says .Cells are invalid

Comment: if i wanted to search for a wildcard of the word would i just add a * after fruits?  Like Fruits & "*"

Comment: No it would be different.  that is a new question, please provide a new post with what you have tried and your specific requirements. @Tara